# MVVM pattern in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Kendo Grid control to display some data and it's working OK. This is the code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
          .Name("MyGrid")
          .ToolBar(toolbar =>
              {
                  toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Line").HtmlAttributes(new { @Class = "btn btn-primary" });
              })
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Description).HtmlAttributes(new {style = "font-size: 9pt;"});
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Value);
                  columns.Command(cmd =>
                      {
                          cmd.Edit();
                          cmd.Destroy();
                      }).Width(200);
              })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
          .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
          .DataSource(data => data
                                  .Ajax()
                                  .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                                  .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                                  .ServerOperation(false)
                                  .Read(read => read.Action("ReadAction", "MyController"))
                                  .Create(create => create.Action("CreateAction", "MyController"))
                                  .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateAction", "MyController"))
                                  .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("DeleteAction", "MyController"))
          ))
```

The code above is working without any problem. Now, what I'm trying to implement is to display the same data using the MVVM pattern. I mean, I would like to have the same operations (create, update, delete) in my viewmodel without calling the server actions of my controller as the code above does.

I have google it for a while but without any luck.

Any help would be very appreciate

Comment: check this [demo section](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/mvvm)